# Restrict one current submission per device

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

I would like to store one user preference per iOS and android device in a database.

Ideally it would be per user but as I don't want to maintain a login system. I want to do it this way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Note first that you can use the anonymous user system to create users for you and you could look at using that. You could also create a real user with randomly generated (UUID) username and password which are then stored in the keychain.

Alternatively, use the installation which is created for each device.

Comment: Is the installation unique and single for one device?

Comment: Yes, it is per device